# Ubuntu 18.04 with RTL8723BE wifi is weak also with changing antenna number

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04, hp

first of all i want to say that i **TRIED EVERYTHING I WAS ABLE TO FIND ON INTERNET ( literally every question on forum ubuntu and askubuntu** but wifi is still weak

information:

- 4.15.0-45-generic ( ubuntu fresh install )
- hp computer
- secure boot disable

**EDIT : SOLVED INSTALLING UBUNTU 18.10**

i've tried to git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/ and install it; select the antenna and check wifi strength ( nothing change )

what else can i do?

Comment: Take it apart and put the antenna wire on the other connector or see https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and run the wireless script and edit the question to include results

Comment: @Jeremy31 i edit the question, i put the file

Comment: Since it is closed as a dupe, do `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` then reboot

Comment: @Jeremy31 nope, it doesn't fix it

Comment: Do `./wireless-info && cat wireless-info.txt | nc termbin.com 9999` post URL for new script result